# Java RXTXcomm Lib does not load or is not to be found

Tags: java, raspbian, rxtx

I want to do a small test with a nanoCUL868 USB device in order to transmit some signal to remote devices. The stick works with some 3rd party software and I was able to communicate with the remote device. I now want to test this stick with the following code in JAVA:

```
package de.saltest.home;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.openmuc.jrxtx.Parity;
import org.openmuc.jrxtx.SerialPort;
import org.openmuc.jrxtx.SerialPortBuilder;

public class SomfyCULTest {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SomfyCULTest.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        log.info("Opening port ttyUSB0");
        SerialPort port = SerialPortBuilder.newBuilder("/dev/ttyAMA0").setBaudRate(9600).setParity(Parity.NONE).build();
        OutputStream out = port.getOutputStream();

        String commandLEDOn = "l01\n";
        String commandLEDOff = "l00\n";

        String encryptionKey = "A1";
        // C - Command (1 = My, 2 = Up, 4 = Down, 8 = Prog)
        String command = "2";
        String rollingCode = "001D";
        String address = "000029";
        String somfyCommand = "Ys" + encryptionKey + command + "0" + rollingCode + address + "\n";
        out.write(somfyCommand.getBytes());
        out.close();
        port.close();

        log.info("Closed port");
    }

}
```

I have installed Oracle Java on a Rasperry Pi 3 and also got the librtrx-java via apt-get. A `dpkg-query -L librxtx-java` yields:

```
/usr/lib/jni/librxtxRS485.so
/usr/lib/jni/librxtxRaw.so
/usr/lib/jni/librxtxI2C.so
/usr/lib/jni/librxtxParallel.so
/usr/lib/jni/librxtxSerial.so
/usr/share/java/RXTXcomm.jar
```

So, I assume those libraries are correctly installed for the right platform.
If I use javac to compile my code:

I get the following error message:

```
javac -classpath /usr/lib/jni -cp /usr/share/java/RXTXcomm.jar:. src/main/java/de/saltest/home/SomfyCULTest.java
src/main/java/de/saltest/home/SomfyCULTest.java:7: error: package org.openmuc.jrxtx does not exist
import org.openmuc.jrxtx.Parity;
                        ^
```

I have also a maven project which compiles fine using this code, however, I cant execute it because of the following error:

```
 mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=de.saltest.home.SomfyCULTest

[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) @ serialTest ---
Okt 07, 2018 3:25:41 PM de.saltest.home.SomfyCULTest main
INFORMATION: Opening port ttyUSB0
Could not load lib from jar and from system.
gnu.io.LibLoadException: directory does not exist /libs
        at gnu.io.LibraryLoader.loadLib(LibraryLoader.java:65)
        at gnu.io.LibraryLoader.loadLibsFromJar(LibraryLoader.java:48)
        at gnu.io.LibraryLoader.loadRxtxNative(LibraryLoader.java:29)
        at gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver.<clinit>(RXTXCommDriver.java:85)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:104)
        at org.openmuc.jrxtx.JRxTxPort.openSerialPort(JRxTxPort.java:50)
        at org.openmuc.jrxtx.SerialPortBuilder.build(SerialPortBuilder.java:166)
        at de.saltest.home.SomfyCULTest.main(SomfyCULTest.java:24)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
```

From here I'm lost. I have tried many things like copying libraries to different places like suggested in some other posts. I have also changed the classpath and many other things I could think of. However, nothing seems to work. The only thing I find strange is that I try to use java.io. but the code tries to load gnu.io. May be there is some mismatch?
Any help or solution is really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What seems to be the solution is to add a plugin to the maven build which produces a JAR with all dependencies included. Like described here: https://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/
However, what's still odd, you have to add the library path like mentioned above:

`-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni`

For my understanding this should not be necessary anymore. Nevertheless, without the path it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add the native path of the library as start parameter:

```
-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried it already, however it does not seem to work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue, for resolve the issues, steps that worked for me

```
Step1. add RXTXcomm.jar and RXTXcomm-2.2pre2.jar in JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext

Step2:- create war file using eclipse or anything

Step3: On the client environment these jar should be store in same location

Step4: Add RXTXcomm.jar and RXTXcomm-2.2pre2.jar in JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext of client environment.
```

Note:- If you not geting the data from serial device then check locks on the serial port, It may be other thread or process already occupied or not release the lock.

For checking locks on port,

command is `fuser /dev/ttyS0` then

```
kill -9 PID
```

I hope this will be work.
Working with centos7